# Join a la misma tabla con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join

Tengo una tabla `Fixture`, la cual contiene `Fixture.idLocal, Fixture.idVisitante`, ambas contienen como clave foranea `Equipo.id`.

Estoy queriendo mostrar los nombres (Equipo.Nombre) de ambos equipos, pero solo me muestra el del segundo joint

```
$fixture=DB::table('fixture')
            ->join('equipo as equipolocal','fixture.idLocal', '=', 'equipolocal.id')
            ->join('equipo as equipovisitante','fixture.idVisitante', '=', 'equipovisitante.id')
            ->get();
            var_dump($fixture);
            die();
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

> { ["id"]=> int(22) ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> NULL
> ["idCategoria"]=> int(2) ["idLocal"]=> int(23) ["idVisitante"]=>
> int(22) ["fecha"]=> int(1) ["Nombre"]=> string(5) "Tigre"
> ["idLocalidad"]=> int(1) } } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque es a la misma tabla, son dos `joins` distintos por lo que considero que:

- En tu `SELECT` debes indicar de forma explícita las columnas que deseas recuperar y de que alias provienen.

  ```
  ->select('equipolocal.columna1', 'equipolocal.columna2', 'equipovisitante.columna1', 'equipovisitante.columna2')
  ........
  ```